# How to pass param value to the Invoke-Command cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, parameters, invoke-command

I wrote a simple [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script to modify hosts file on remote machines but something goes wrong.

Script:

```
param(
   [string]$value
)

$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$hosts = "172.28.30.45","172.28.30.46"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$pass

ForEach ($x in $hosts){
   echo "Write in $x , value: $value"
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -ScriptBlock {Add-Content -Path "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" -Value $value} -Credential $cred
   echo "Finish writing."
}

echo "End of PS script."
```

When run, it writes a new **empty line** for each hosts file. This line `echo "Write in $x , value: $value"` displays **$value** value.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *pass the parameter to the scriptblock* by defining a `param` section within your scriptblock and pass the parameters using `-ArgumentList` :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -ScriptBlock {
    param
    (
        [string]$value
    )
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" -Value $value
    } -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $value
```

Or you leverage the `using:` variable prefix:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $x -ScriptBlock {
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" -Value $using:value
    } -Credential $cred
```